Adding new columns to the fact and dimension tables after the SSIS project deploying to the database
I need to know what are the methods that we can add new columns to the fact table and dimension tables to the data warehouse after the SSIS solution deploying to the database.
I have developed the datawarehouse using SSIS. Datawarehouse has been built using Microsoft dynamics gp ERP data. For the datawarehouse, I have only extracted and loaded some required columns to the fact and dimension table. If I have to add another column after I deploy this project to the database what are the methods. Will there be NULL values after adding new columns to the fact and dimension tables.
Currently, I add the new column and do the initial load again and again when I add a new column.

From my experience over two decades I consider two things pre-requisites:

Test and Prod environment as minimum
Source control

Nice to have:

Implementation and Rollback scripts including structural and data changes

New columns
Fact
Adding a new column can be done with a default value. Normally I use a default value which indicates UNKNOWN. This value is in the dimension and on reports it becomes easily visible if any data from the fact has incorrect dimension connections.
new dimension link
ALTER TABLE {schema}.{TableName}
  ADD {id for dimension} {type} NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_{schema}_{TableName}_{id for dimension} DEFAULT( {default value for UNKNOWN} )
      WITH VALUES
;

This {default value for UNKNOWN} has an entry in the dimension table.
new fact column
ALTER TABLE {schema}.{TableName}
  ADD {newcolumn} {type} NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_{schema}_{TableName}_{newcolumn} DEFAULT( {default value for UNKNOWN} )
      WITH VALUES
;

Default value for new fact columns depend on type. Depending on source data:

numbers / quantities / monetary value => zero value as this has least impact though hard to find later
alternative: a very distinct value I can identify easily later like 4711
date => 9000-01-01 - every developer has a substitute date in mind to capture a NULL value to avoid trinary logic
boolean => tricky and very often I allow and use NULL to fix later

Fix data
Using Update statements to fix the data as best as possible after structural changes.
SSIS
Once Test environment has the structural changes I can then fix the SSIS to include the new column(s).
Deployment to Prod
After testing that both structure changes and SSIS work together in Test environment (maybe even some days in a row) then bundle change request for implementation to Production after changes are recorded in source control.
Conclusion
Successful structure changes of tables along with SSIS will become stable and minimise interruptions with this design pattern.
Not included
There is a whole different approach using tables, views and stored procedures to keep structure and data transfer changes all to SQL Server itself. SSIS is then only used to execute stored procedures in a certain order.
This is not explained here as the question itself is too vague plus this different approach is too long to explain in a forum post.

In our DWH solution normally when I add new column either it's new dimension key or numeric field.
If it's a new Dimension then I update the new fact column(dimension key) with -1(Unknown Dimension)  and if its some new numeric column then update it with 0.
Then update the load from incremental to full load.
Run all these update code in post deployment script.
 Update Fact table
    Set Dimension_Key = -1,
     Numeric_Column = 0

    Update meta table
    Load type = 'Full'

The full load then update the new column with valid data.
Also the new column when added in table it should defined with default value.
